# How to disable percent-encoding in URLs?

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, biber, unicode, urls

I try to add a unicode URL into the bibliography and LaTeX automatically converts the cyrillyc letters into percent-encoding. I found that **hyperref** is responsible for this, but I found no way to disable it. It's OK to encode the link itself, but in document I don't need this, the reader wants to see letters instead of character codes. I really don't want to print this `https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLAM_(%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4)` on papaer, this gives no useful information to reader.

TeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{1.bib}

\begin{document}
Hello \cite{Wiki:SLAM}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

1.bib:

```
@InCollection{Wiki:SLAM,
  title     = {SLAM (метод)},
  booktitle = {Википедия~"--- свободная энциклопедия},
  organization = {Wikimedia Foundation, Inc.},
  address    = {США},
  date      = {2016-05-23},
  url       = {https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLAM_(метод)},
  urldate   = {2017-02-22},
  language  = {russian},
}
```

Result:

[image: result]

I want to have `https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLAM_(метод)` in the URL.

Comment: I still have trouble with this. Are there no solutions appeard after about two years? I even tried to use a `usera` field for URLs, but `\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\mkbibacro{URL}\addcolon\space\\thefield{usera}}` did not work ((

Answer (score 13):

A current biber knows the option `--nouri-encode` and then you get this

[image]

which isn't a sensible output either.

With a unicode engine like lualatex or xelatex and such a document (and again with `--nouri-encode`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial Unicode MS} %something with cyrillic 
\setmonofont{Arial Unicode MS} %something with cyrillic
\begin{document}
Hello \cite{Wiki:SLAM}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Adding hyperref to the document will give the same output but the link will be wrong:

[image]

### Edit

As the comment made clear that pdflatex solution is needed some background info: As the following example demonstrates `url.sty` can't in a realiable way print non-ascii chars. Depending on the surrounding language (and also depending on packages like hyperref) you get all sorts of wrong output.

The only way to get a perfect output is to handcraft it. This means that if you want this from a bib-file you will have to put the print version of the url in some extra field and change the biblatex macros for the url to use them.

```
\documentclass[parskip=half-]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

\minisec{Russian / T2A-encoding}

normal text:
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLAM\_(метод)

url: \url{https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLAM_(метод)} %wrong output

{%correct output, \babelhyphen{empty} for breakpoint, _ has been escaped to \_
  \fontencoding{T1}\ttfamily
  https://\babelhyphen{empty}ru.\babelhyphen{empty}wikipedia.\babelhyphen{empty}org/%
  \babelhyphen{empty}wiki/\babelhyphen{empty}SLAM\_({\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont метод})
}

\selectlanguage{english}
\minisec{English / T1-encoding}

normal text: % https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLAM\_(метод) %errors

url: \url{https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLAM_(метод)} %wrong output  

{%correct output, \babelhyphen{empty} for breakpoint, _ has been escaped to \_
 \fontencoding{T1}\ttfamily
  https://\babelhyphen{empty}ru.\babelhyphen{empty}wikipedia.\babelhyphen{empty}org/%
  \babelhyphen{empty}wiki/\babelhyphen{empty}SLAM\_({\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont метод})
} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So there's no way to handle this in pure LaTex?

Comment: I should inform that I use fonts from pscyr and they absolutely support Cyrillic. Something strange is going on here and I start to think about a bug in biber

Comment: It is not biber but the url command. Try out `\url{метод}` with and without hyperref.

Comment: I tried and it did not produce percent encoding. It produced another unreadable result. Like cyrillic letters in LaTeX commands

Comment: That's what I meant: With pdflatex the \url command can't correctly print the url if it contains cyrillic. biber can't do anything about it. With luatex there is more hope.

Comment: That's sad... Well, maybe I really should switch to XeLaTeX, now when I think about it, I see that fonts in LaTeX make really much problems. Thanks for help.

Comment: Actually it looks as if xelatex does it best currently. The faulty link in luatex seems to be a bug.

Comment: OK, I found out that I can't use XeLaTeX, because it does not supported by the documentclass I need (disser). And also I found out that `biber` is responsible for the broken encoding.
I did `\renewcommand{\url}[1]{#1}` and the text was still broken. Seems like it's UTF8->CP1251, but I had no luch to decypher the output. The problem is still open... Unfortunately, I need it to be solved in LaTeX

Comment: I thought a bit about this problem in the last days. And imho the best would be to put the correct (percent encoded) url in the url field of the bib, and to add a version for printing in some user field (e.g. usera). This version could then be fine tuned. Changing biblatex to use \href{url}{usera} shouldn't be so difficult. And please stop to think that something is broken: percent encoding is the only correct form for an url see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding. Your browser does this conversion internally too.

Comment: Percent-encoding is an ugly workaround for old non-utf8-enabled systems remain working on the web. There's no good for user. Especially the one who is used to read the dead-tree versions of books and papers. I understand that maybe there will be no people who will type the url from bibliography, but for a reader, there's no difference between percent-encoding and broken-encoding. I filed a ticket for biber https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/160. I used the custom filed for URLs in my previous paper and now I try to do everything in a way it should be done...

Comment: You seem not to understand the difference between what you see and what your browser really uses. If you have the chrome browser or firefox: Enter your link, then go to the address bar, select the link and paste it in your editor. Beside this it doesn't make sense to add a ticket to biber. It is not biber's fault that with pdflatex `url.sty` can not reliably print an url with cyrillic chars  and that you can't use a real unicode engine. Add a ticket to the tracker of your class that it adapts to unicode.

Comment: I added an edit regarding the pdflatex problem.

Comment: I clearly understand that my browser does percent-encoding before rquesting servers, I just want to say that my brain does not. Browser is not the one who will read my paper, heh. As you may notice, the url is usually displayed in unicode even in the address bar. Yes, it will be percent-encoded after copying (for total comparability), this makes difficulties in my case. Thank you very much for help.

Comment: As discussed in the answer below, current biber replaced `--nouri-encode` with a new field `urlraw`.

Answer (score 7):

Using XeLaTeX, there actually is a solution.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\urlstyle{same} % to use a font with Cyrillic characters

\addbibresource{1.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{%
  \mkbibacro{URL}\addcolon\space
  \href{#1}{\nolinkurl{\thefield{urlraw}}}}


\begin{document}
Hello \cite{Wiki:SLAM}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

(The file `1.bib` is as above.)  The code uses a new feature of biber (starting with version 2.8): it provides the original, unconverted URL data in the field `urlraw` (and there is no longer an option `--nouri-encode`, BTW).  We redefine the `url` field formatter to call `\href` with the data from `urlraw` as the second argument.

[image: 1.png]

---

For CJK characters in bibliography entries there is also a simple solution.

First, the file `2.bib`.

```
@online{Gakushyu,
  author  = {Wikipedia},
  title   = {学習指導要領 [Gakushū-shidō-yōryō]},
  langid  = {japanese},
  date    = {2017-12-24},
  url     = {https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/学習指導要領#2020年（平成32年）_-},
  urldate = {2018-01-15},
}
```

And here an input example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage[CJKmath]{xeCJK}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\addbibresource{2.bib}
\setCJKmainfont{ipam.ttf}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{%
  \mkbibacro{URL}\addcolon\space
  \href{#1}{\nolinkurl{\thefield{urlraw}}}}


\begin{document}
Hello \cite{Gakushyu}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

`\url` (and `\nolinkurl`) handle URLs in math mode, and option `CJKmath` activates CJK support for math.

[image: cjk.png]

A minor disadvantage is that strings of CJK characters can't be broken.  In most cases this shouldn't be a problem.  However, if you really need that, a more elaborate solution is necessary that avoids `\nolinkurl`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\addbibresource{2.bib}
\setCJKmainfont{ipam.ttf}

\begingroup
  \XeTeXinterchartokenstate = 1
  \newXeTeXintercharclass \urlBreakClass
\endgroup

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{%
  \begingroup
    \XeTeXinterchartokenstate = 1
    \XeTeXcharclass `\/ \urlBreakClass
    \XeTeXinterchartoks \urlBreakClass 0 {\allowbreak}%
    \XeTeXinterchartoks \urlBreakClass 1 {%
      \allowbreak
      \csname xeCJK_class_group_begin:\endcsname
      \csname xeCJK_select_font:\endcsname
      \csname xeCJK_clear_inter_class_toks:nn\endcsname{Default}{CJK}%
      \csname xeCJK_clear_Boundary_and_CJK_toks:\endcsname
      \CJKsymbol}%
    \mkbibacro{URL}\addcolon\space\href{#1}{\thefield{urlraw}}%
  \endgroup}


\begin{document}
Hello \cite{Gakushyu}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: 2.png]

To allow line breaks after `/` (but not between the two slashes in `//`) we use the `\XeTeXcharclass` feature: We define a new character class for `/`, then calling `\allowbreak` if we have a transition from `/` to a normal character.  It is straightforward to add more characters to the new class if desired.

Because we define a separate class for `/`, xeCJK's mechanism doesn't get applied to the character following it, and we have to insert the corresponding code into our class token list (this is a hack; hopefully, there will be a better solution in the future).  The five lines after `\allowbreak` have been taken from file `xeCJK.sty` (version 3.5.1), lines 740ff.  Since xeCJK is written in LaTeX3, we use `\csname` to call the macros.  Note that the above code covers only the simplest case, namely `/` followed by an ordinary CJK character (which xeCJK assigns to class 1).

Answer (score 0):

After two years, there's still no solution. All I managed to do is to handcraft the entity like this:

```
@Misc{Wiki:SLAM,
    title        = {SLAM (метод) [Электронный ресурс] // Википедия~--- свободная энциклопедия},
    year         = {2016},
    howpublished = {URL: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLAM\_(метод) (дата обр.~22.02.2017)},
    language     = {russian},
}
```