# Break URL in Bibtex reference without losing the link, with hyperref package and LaTeX compiler

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, urls, dvi

I am trying to properly break some of the url in my references.
When using `\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}`, the url breaks but the link disappear (not clickable) even though the blue color is still present. 
I tried various combinations of the `url` and `hyperref`packages with their options, I still face the same issue : either the url does not break, or the link disapper.

As my file includes PostScript files, I have to compile through DVI->PS->PDF.It seems the problem comes mainly from here, as compiling the MWE directly to PDF works. I use TeXStudio.

EDIT: shorter MWE, clarification of the issue. The use of breakurl or url packages don't break the url.

```
\documentclass[aps, reprint,prmat,twocolumn]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=blue,
citecolor=blue,
urlcolor=blue,}

\begin{document}
Short citation\cite{takeda_visualization_2005}. Long citation\cite{LandoltBornstein2002}

\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

MWE of the url not breaking but working

```
\documentclass[aps, reprint,prmat,twocolumn]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{breakurl}

\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=blue,
citecolor=blue,
urlcolor=blue,}

\begin{document}
blabla\cite{takeda_visualization_2005}. Ahahah\cite{LandoltBornstein2002}

\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

bibliography.bib

```
@book{LandoltBornstein2002,
editor="Madelung, O.
and R{\"o}ssler, U.
and Schulz, M.",
title="Silicon ({Si}), band structure: Datasheet from {L}andolt-{B}{\"o}rnstein - {Group III Condensed Matter {\textperiodcentered} Volume 41A1$\beta$: ``Group IV Elements, IV-IV and III-V Compounds. Part b - Electronic, Transport, Optical and Other Properties''}",
publisher= "Springer-Verlag Berlin Heidelberg",
doi="10.1007/10832182_432",
url="https://materials.springer.com/lb/docs/sm_lbs_978-3-540-31356-4_432",
urldate ={2018-06-11},
year={2002}
}

@article{takeda_visualization_2005,
title = {Visualization of In-Plane Dispersion of Hole Subbands by Photoelectron Spectroscopy},
volume = {94},
year = 2005,
month = Jan,
issn = {0031-9007, 1079-7114},
url = {https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.94.037401},
doi = {10.1103/PhysRevLett.94.037401},
number = {3},
journal = {Physical Review Letters},
author = {Takeda, Sakura Nishino and Higashi, Naoto and Daimon, Hiroshi},
urldate = {2018-05-12},
date = {2005-01-24},
pages={-},
langid = {english}}
```

Comment: I get a warning that the driver for `dvi` does not support the option `breaklinks` for hyperref. There is a package called https://ctan.org/pkg/breakurl that says it could help here.

Comment: You wrote that "I am trying to properly break some of the url in my references." However, the two formatted bibliographic entries shown above do not appear to contains URL strings. This makes it very difficult to tell what may be going on. Please edit your code and provide examples of bibliographic entries that contain URL strings.

Comment: Please also tell us *how* you created the `thebibliography` environment shown above. Did you create it entirely by hand, or with the help of either natbib/bibtex or biblatex/biber?

Comment: @moewe : the package breakurl does not break my url.
@Mico indeed. I made substential changes in my exemple. The issue seems to be the size of the title, and not of the url in itself. I decided to use a `.bib` file for the MWE, as it displays the same issue.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/456680/change-url-to-normal-text-in-biblatex/456682?noredirect=1#comment1148789_456682 may help you, but this expect biblatex to work

Comment: @MadyYuvi biblatex is not compatible with my file, because of RevTex I think, which loads natbib automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution : use EPS files instead of PS.

There is a conflict between the way `hyperref` handles the url in the references and the `DVI->PS->PDF` process. By converting my PS figures to EPS, I was able to compile directecly to PDF as EPS are automatically converted to pdf during the compilation, but PS files are not.

Comment: Yes, it was a bug in `DVIPS`, also note that instead of converting `EPS to PDF`, better you can switch to `XeLaTeX`, which accepts both `EPS` and `PDF` formats

Answer (score -1):

You can also try using the package `\usepackage{breakurl}` instead of `\usepackage{url}`.

Comment: No, your suggestion doesn't work well, it was a bug in `DVIPS`