# Displaying cyrillic letters in url inside bibliography

Tags: biblatex, urls, cyrillic

I want to cite a url that contains cyrillic letters: `wikipedia.org/wiki/Апории_Зенона`
However it is displayed as

[image]

Is there any way to display it as `https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Апории_Зенона`?

I am using LuaLaTeX with `biblatex`

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\setmainfont{FreeSerif}
\setsansfont{FreeSans}
\setmonofont{FreeMono}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[
        backend     =   biber,%
        style       =   numeric,%
        sortlocale  =   en_US,%
        language    =   auto,
    ]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{b.bib}


\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

text

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

**Bibliography**

```
@online{zenon,
    author = {{Зенон Элейский}},
    title  = {Апории Зенона},
    url    = {https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Апории_Зенона}
}
```

Comment: I guess that the solutions in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/410883/4427 are what you're looking for.

Comment: @egreg yes, thank you, this works

Comment: @egreg yes, I am going to mark this as duplicate