# How to prevent biber from transforming urls containing Sanskrit diacritics into something ugly?

Tags: biblatex, biber

I have a cosmetic problem with the document I am currently working on.

This entry in my .bib:

```
codex{mscodex,
  title={Gorakṣayogaśāstra},
  note={NGMPP, B22/44, Palmblatt, Nevārī},
  url = {http://catalogue-old.ngmcp.uni-hamburg.de/wiki/B_24-44_(Gorakṣayogaśāstra)},
  date={Zugriff: 12.07.2022},
  address={National Archives Kathmandu},
  keywords={codex},
}
```

Will print once I cite the entry with \cite{mscodex} the following:

> Gorakṣayogaśāstra. NGMPP, B22/44, Palmblatt, Nevārī. uRl:
> %5Curl%7Bhttp
> ://catalogue-old.ngmcp.uni-hamburg.de/wiki/B_24-44_(Gorak%E1%B9
> %A3ayoga%C5%9B%C4%81stra)%7D.

As you can see the URL which originally contains Sanskrit diacritics is printed very ugly.

Anyone knows how to solve this? I would be very happy and grateful!

Best wishes,
Nils

Comment: URLs are _supposed_ to be percent encoded if they contain non-ASCII characters: this is not Biber's 'fault'

Comment: Don't use `\url` inside the value.  And always make a complete example, we won't have to guess how you print sanskrit outside of the url. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/599111/2388

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks, it is only the fault of my ignorance.

Comment: But thanks to @UlrikeFischer everything works perfectly now.